# Apply a ReceivedTime = Today's Date filter in Items.Restrict

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, unmanaged, outlook-2010

I am trying to filter items in a folder using the code below:

```
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '9/20/2014'";
items = InboxFolder.Items; // Line 1
items = InboxFolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter); //Line 2
```

When line 2 executes, it returns the items of 9/20/2014

I want items of 9/21/2014 (as ReceivedTime > 9/20/2014).

How can I get items for today, i.e. **ReceivedTime = Today's Date**?

Find Method is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by changing `sFilter` :

```
sFilter =" [ReceivedTime] >= '2014-09-21 00:00' "
```

Comment: With this the result is zero. Which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook interop needs some specific Date Format as a parameter of Restrict method.

you can use equal to sign with greater than >=

please convert your Date Format into this **('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')**, please make sure to put your date into a single quote.

```
var filter = "[ReceivedTime] >='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") + "' ";
```

In your case it would be fine also

```
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '09/20/2014'";
```

To get emails between two dates then you can use and operator

```
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '09/20/2014' and [ReceivedTime] <= '09/28/2014'";
```

you can use this format also

```
var filter = "[ReceivedTime] >='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + "' ";
```